# When to perform a 3D collision detection in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, collision-detection

I am making a program that uses various advanced graphics methods. For now, two Wavefront obj models are imported and rendered on screen. I am trying to implement a brute force triangle-triangle collision detection between these two objects but my worry is when to perform these operation. I won't have animation and motion in this program, all I want to do is when I translate (glTranslate) the one object so that it collides with the other, to color the colliding triangles.

Should my collision detection function work with my inital model vertices or I need to obtain somehow current coordinates??

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to separate the moving (physics if you will) from the drawing. You can use an idle function or timer function to move the wavefronts and check for collisions and simply mark the triangles as collided (or whatever you want to indicate they collided) and then force a redraw of the screen and your drawing code should simply take care of clearing the screen and redrawing all the vertices and coloring them appropriately based on whether they are marked as collided or not.

The collision detection will most likely work with your model vertices but you need to keep track of where in "space" your object is to do the math appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

it would be best to separate those two modules: rendering and physics/collision.

thus one object has two representations: one is for rendering (textures, models geometry, materials, etc) and one for physics (bounding box, word space position, etc)

- physics do not have to be so perfect and usually only some mesh approximation is needed. So for a house object we would use only bounding box 
  or bounding sphere to test collision.
- another thing is collision hierarchy: from low resolution to high. First test only bounding spheres (cheap test), then move gradually to triangle to triangle collision test (quite expensive)